# Where does music file from documents go when airdropped to connected devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I download music on the documents app and I wanted to airdrop a song from my iPhone, to iPad. They are both connected so it doesn’t ask and just receives it. And that’s the problem. Idk where it is! I have a files app and documents app on my iPad and I looked and searched for it everywhere. It definitely received it because I heard the sound of when you receive airdropped stuff. I want to find it and delete it so it won’t take up storage. Someone, please help.

Comment: Did you try ios spotlight ? Pulling down on empty screen

Answer (score 2):

AirDrop files are stored in the app that matches them.

For example, pictures will be saved in your Photos app. A presentation will be saved in Keynote. Contacts will be saved in Contacts. And so on.

After you've sent or received an AirDrop file, check the app that matches the file type to ensure it went to the right place and was saved. It should automatically save and open in that app's files.